# Center a text inside an spinning element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple loader animation and I want to add a loading text inside the circle.

As I'm spinning the `.slide-loader` and my text is inside it I've tried to exclude the `.loader-text` but it still spins?! how can I fix the loader-text inside the circle?

Here is the code:

```css
.slide-loader:not(.loader-text) { 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;


}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
  <div class="slide-loader">
    <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```css
  .slide-loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;


  }


  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="slide-loader">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't..as such, if you rotate the parent you rotate the child. You need to rotate the text the other way at the same time.

Then center the text any way you wish, perhaps with flexbox....

```css
.slide-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader-text {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-loader">
  <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I made this work around and works perfectly.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="slide-loader"></div>
   <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

```
 

       .slide-loader{ 
      grid-row: 1/-1;
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      margin: auto;
      border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
    .container{
      width: 200px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 20px 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: auto 60px auto;
    }
    .loader-text{
      grid-row: 2;
      grid-column: 2;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element (`::before`) for the rotating area, and center the text with a flexbox:

```css
.slide-loader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.slide-loader::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  content: '';
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-loader">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The spinner and text can be siblings and you can center both relative to the parent:

```css
.slide-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  /*Center spinner with these 4 lines*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.loader-text {
  position: absolute;
  /*Center text with these 3 lines*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-loader">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slide-loader:not(.loader-text) { 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 6px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 6px solid #3498db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;


}
.container {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader-text">Loading...</div>
  <div class="slide-loader">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```